# Как отключить в ViewPager скролинг?

Tags: android

```
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сильно пролистать слева на права то 2 зеленный фрагмент начнет потихоньку открываться, по 5 7 пикселей...Как полностью откулючить скролинг в ViewPager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте свой собственный клас, унаследованный от `ViewPager`, и переопределите у него `onTouchEvent` и `onIntersectTouchEvent` следующим образом

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    } 

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    } 

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    } 
}
```

И дальше в разметке используйте `<com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager>` вместо `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`

И дальше в коде делайте так:

```
CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false); //выключить скрол
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true); //включить скрол
```

Comment: Дак я же почти это и сделал, только сразу метод onTouchEvent выключил...но все равно ведь не работает если сильно дернукть

Comment: @xTIGRx, вы сделали через установку лиснера, а тут переопределены 2 метода. Попробуйте так сделать.